# How do i change a price when stock is "0" woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to change a price when stock is "0"?

I have a "reguler price" and "another price" in the admin side. "another price" is a metadata (you can see in code -> '_alg_msrp').
I trigger with this code :

```
if($product->stock_quantity == 0 ){
    function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
        global $post, $blog_id;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_alg_msrp', true );

        return $price;
    }
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
}
```

The price does change but I want it only to change on the front side, not on the admin side. This code change the whole view. I mean, how can it affect only the front page, not the admin page, like in "Products" tab in WooCommerce. 
Thanks for any Suggest.

Comment: you can add `&& ! is_admin()` on your `if`

Comment: where i should place that?

Comment: which view? please? or just add in to my code?

Comment: @Sidik see my answer hook you are using is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change it so the logic is inside the function:

```
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
    if ( is_admin() || $product->stock_quantity != 0 ) 
        return $price;

    $custom_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_alg_msrp', true );
    return ($custom_price == '') ? $price : $custom_price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
```

This will return custom price only if it's not empty. Otherwise it will return the regular price.

Comment: "woocommerce_get_price" hook you are using is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

It depend where you want to change, for simple product

"woocommerce_get_price" is deprecated since version 3.0.0

Use "woocommerce_product_get_price" instead.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'new_price', 11, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'new_price', 11, 2 );
function new_price( $price, $product ) {
    if($product && !is_admin()){
      if($product->stock_quantity == 0 ){
       $new_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_alg_msrp', true );
       if($new_price){
        return $new_price;
       }
      }
    }
    return $price;
}
```